# How often does AWS refresh billing regarding EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

About 10h-18h ago I lauched several spot instances and used them for some time before I terminated them.

The AWS "Billing & Cost Management Dashboard" keeps showing me zeroes...

How do I track my expenses?
Do I need to enable something?

P.S. It's an old account and as I understand there is no free tier here

Comment: There is no real time view into the billing system, but the AWS Cost Explorer is probably your best bet - have you tried that?

Comment: AWS Cost Explorer shows zeroes same as "Billing & Cost Management Dashboard"

Answer (score 1):

It refreshed almost at 24h mark...
aws billing refresh speed is remarkably slow